# Login to tty works but not in gnome

Tags: linux, gnome, login

I am able to login on a tty, but not on GNOME.
I can confirm that the root directory has a `.XAuthority` file.

This image shows GNOME login screen after a `loginctl unlock-sessions`:

[image: gnome login buggy screen]

journalctl gives me: `gdm-pam unable to locate daemon control file`. `gdm-password` opens session and unlocks keyring but it closes. It could be the `gdmdisplay session never registered`.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1924079

Is there any logs I can take a look at?

How can I solve it? Will it be necessary to reinstall GNOME or even Linux?

Not sure how to connect to Wi-Fi from the terminal for the GNOME reinstall.

I got to this stage by locking the account and then booting with rescue disk, chrooting, changing password and having a .autorelabel made to restore SELinux context and permissions, and booting.

On fedora 5.15.11.

Comment: Have a look into `journalctl -r`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work…

On file /etc/gdm/custom.conf

Uncommented #WaylandEnable=false

And:

```
 systemctl restart gdm
```

This will use Xorg backend. Wayland by default and Xorg only if Wayland backend cannot be started.

Good simple log of problems on

```
 systemctl status gdm
```

But this initial change did not work…

[image: status]

Comment: Your answer is unclear. Please provide detailed information.